# broken edges union-find Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, union-find

I need some help to figure out union-find problem.
Here is the question.

> There's an undirected connected graph with n nodes labeled 1..n. But
>   some of the edges has been broken disconnecting the graph. Find the
>   minimum cost to repair the edges so that all the nodes are once again
>   accessible from each other.
>
> Input:
>
> n, an int representing the total number of nodes.
>   edges, a list of
>   integer pair representing the nodes connected by an edge.
>   edgesToRepair, a list where each element is a triplet representing the
>   pair of nodes between which an edge is currently broken and the cost
>   of repearing that edge, respectively
>   (e.g. [1, 2, 12] means to repear
>   an edge between nodes 1 and 2, the cost would be 12).
>
> Example 1:
>   Input: n = 5, edges = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [1, 5]],
>   edgesToRepair = [[1, 2, 12], [3, 4, 30], [1, 5, 8]]
>
> Output: 20
>   There are 3 connected components due to broken edges:
>   [1], [2, 3] and [4, 5]. We can connect these components into a single
>   component by repearing the edges between nodes 1 and 2, and nodes 1
>   and 5 at a minimum cost 12 + 8 = 20.

```
public int minCostRepairEdges(int N, int[][] edges, int[][] edgesToRepair){

    int[] unionFind = new int[N+1];
    int totalEdges=0;
    for(int[] edge : edges){
        int ua = edge[0]; //node1
        int ub = edge[1]; //node2
        unionFind[ua] = ub;
        totalEdges++;
    }

    //change unionFind for some broken edge 
    for(int[] broken : edgesToRepair){
        int ua = Find(unionFind, broken[0]);
        int ub = Find(unionFind, broken[1]);
        if(ua == ub){
            unionFind[ua] = 0;
        }
    }

    Arrays.sort(edgesToRepair, (a,b)->(a[2]-b[2]));

    int cost=0;
    for(int[] i : edgesToRepair){
        int ua = Find(unionFind, i[0]);
        int ub = Find(unionFind, i[1]);

        if(ua != ub){
            unionFind[ua] = ub;
            cost += i[2];
            totalEdges++;
        }
    }
    return edgesToRepair==N-1 ? cost : -1;
}

public int find(int[] uf, int find){
    if(uf[find]==0) return find;
    uf[find] = find(uf, uf[find]);
    return uf[find];
}
```

And Above is my code so far.

My idea is that
First Adding all edges (given edges[][]) to UnionFind and then Update it based on given edgesToRepair Info. (if edge was broken then going to update it in union -find)
Then just try to do basic union-find algorithm to connect two nodes with minimum cost.

Any wrong approach in here?
First, I have trouble updating unionFind when it was broken.
I can't figure out how to handle unbroken edges between two nodes.

Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're supposed to use Kruskal's algorithm to find a minimum cost spanning tree consisting of the existing edges and broken (repaired) edges:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm

Just consider the existing edges to have 0 cost, while the broken edges have their repair cost.